# Is there any function to return the basepath in Zencart?

Tags: zen-cart

Is there any function to return the basepath in Zencart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by `HTTP_SERVER` and `DIR_WS_CATALOG` you can get URL

while

by `DIR_FS_CATALOG` you can get absulute file path

Those are constant defined in configuration file located in includes folder.

There is no need to use any function